Azure Custom Claim Guest/External User
I am trying to add a custom claim in my JWT Token to distinguish between internal and external users in my Web App.
Thus, I did the following App registrations -> <My application> -> Enterprise Application -> Single sign-on -> Attributes & Claims -> Add new claim -> user.usertype

Unfortunatelly, this doesn't return the Guest value that I was hoping for, when I log in and decode the JWT Token. In my case I get for example UserTypeCloudManaged
Is there maybe another Source attribute with this value? I find it pecurial that this attribute is not already set in the default claims.

Hence you also make use of idp claim to differentiate between internal and external users. Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/access-token-claims-reference#payload-claims

@Rukmini I understand. Where can I find the idp claim to add? It is not to be found under Enterprise Application -> Attributes & Claims or  App registrations -> Token Configuration -> Optional Claims. Is this something I would need to add under the Manifest section?

The idp claim may be 'live.com' for guest users

@Rukmini I unfortunatelly don't get it, but maybe I am looking at the wrong token (accessToken). I did try all the versions null,1,2 of accessTokenAcceptedVersion. Perhaps something is wrong with my configs. But at the moment I get the values from the userType. Wouldnt this suffice to check if a user is external or internal? Why would I also need the idp claim? Or is this one or the other?

Otherwise, are you okay using Microsoft Graph API query to check UserType?

@Rukmini For guests, the userType value is UserTypeNoPa. I guess that would suffice if this value is applied globaly :) Concerning the Microsoft Graph API query I am not aware. I will check on this. Thank you so much for this! The docu is a bit confusing.

I think I will just use the App Registration App Roles. Not exactly what I would have liked to do but this seems to be more straightforward. By the way, I rechecked the token and the idp does appear but so far only for the Guests. Real mystery, I tell you that.

For guests, the userType value is UserTypeNoPa and for members what value do you get?

@Rukmini For my internal account UserTypeCloudManaged. I do not find any official documentation stating this though.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Rukmini It is only an alternative. I wouldn't say it is the solution to my question.

Yeah can I post an answer?

@Rukmini Sure you can :)

I added a custom claim in the Enterprise application:

Generated the access token:
Grant type: Authorization code 

Callback URL: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
Auth URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : ClientID
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope: api://XXX/access_as_user


And got UserType claim value as UserTypeCloudManaged same as you:


Note that: user.usertype is not an exposed attribute value, Refer this MsDoc to check the approved exposed attributes values that can be displayed as claims.

Hence to resolve the issue, you need to configure claim conditions based on your requirement and save like below:

Select the User type from dropdown.
For Source select Attribute.
And type the name for value and enter based on your requirement.


Now I generated access token as member and got claim as "UserType": "Member" :

For Guest user, got "UserType": "Guest" :


Beautifully documented! What does thought the following mean? "Note that: user.usertype is not an exposed attribute value,"

To make user.usertype claim to display attributes you need to add claim conditions where as for other claims no need to add claim conditions to expose value
